# Make a specific value unique in a column

Tags: mysql

I am making a users table, and I want to have only 1 row with super administrator role, while the other roles can appear multiple rows. Is there a way to do this on database level? Additionally, is there a way to lock a row from being changed in the database?

Comment: While it is possible for most modifications, it isn't a good idea - because this will definitely reduce performance on insertions/updates/deletions

Comment: Why don't you simply store this one row in an extra table? Then just revoke insert, update and delete rights from everyone but the administrator. If you need to query users together with administrator you can use `union`.

Comment: I was just wondering if it can be done on database level and if it is a good idea. I'm doing this validation on higher level now. Thank you, your answers were helpful. :)